# need help on c++ Regex

Tags: c++, regex

I try to make following code work for my gcc 4.8.1 but i can't . if you need more information ,let me know. thank you so much

```
std::cmatch res;
std::string str = "<h2>I'm a piece of text</h2>";
std::regex rx("<h(.)>([^<]+)");
std::regex_search(str.c_str(), res, rx);
std::cout << res[1] << ". " << res[2] << "\n";
```

output:

```
2. Egg prices
```

according to chris, i need to wait gcc 4.9. if that, how does you implement this design in current gcc(not boost)?
i want to Retrieve matches

Thanks again.

Comment: If you're using libstdc++, it won't support regex until GCC 4.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don´t have a boost env now to test (I´ll do it ASAP), but if you have, try something like:

```
#include<boost/regex>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

int main(){

try{
  std::string str("<h2>I'm a piece of text</h2>");

  boost::regex rx("(<h[1-9]>)(.*)(<\\/h[1-9]>)");
  boost::sregex_iterator it(str.begin(), str.end(), rx);

  std::cout << << (*it)[1] << "\n"; // get group 1

 return 0;
}
```

[Regex 101](http://regex101.com/r/zL9mM5)  is an excelent source to validade your regex!

Comment: i dont allow to use boost. do you have other solution? thanks

Comment: @cppython To use regex, you'll need a regex lib. If you have a very limited scenario (ie, just parse header tags), you can program a kind of simple state machine based on `std::string::substr`, `std::string::find`, etc. If you want to go this way, specify the restrictions of the input and I'll try to help!

Answer (score 0):

As per the error message, you gotta use another library, for example [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html)

If you want to sanitize HTML you should consider using a more specialized technique. I personally do it through [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/). [Gumbo](https://github.com/google/gumbo-parser) might work for C++. Also an XML parser will usually work.